# Ни самого начальника, (ни?) одного из замов

Tags: грамматика

Прозвучала в СМИ конструкция, подобная следующей (в оригинале невероятно длинная - со слуха не буду восстанавливать).

***Устроили мероприятие, но не пригласили ни самого начальника, ни одного из замов.***

Имеется в виду, что вообще ни одного из замов не пригласили. Как поправить? Даже добавление второго "ни" (ни начальника, ни ни одного из замов) ничего не дает - мало того, что грамматика не позволяет, так и смысла-то нет.

Понятно, что в устной речи не такие плюхи иной раз проскакивают даже на микрофон, но вопрос именно в том, а как надо-то?! Если нельзя фразу перестраивать уж совсем на что-то далёкое от исходного.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1: не пригласили ни самого начальника, ни кого-нибудь из замов.

Вариант 2: не пригласили ни самого начальника, ни его замов.

Вариант 3: не пригласили не только самого начальника, но и ни одного из замов.

Comment: 2 и 3 - изменение смысла, пусть и не такое значительное, но оно есть. Что касается 1-го то смысл передан более или менее точно, но акцент все равно смещен. Получается, что пригласить можно было только одного кого-то... Вряд ли о том речь.  Повторюсь, меня игнтересует чисто академическая проблема - построение не только грамматически правильной конструкции, но и тождественной по всех смыслах исходному неграмотному варианту по предполагаемой семантике и акцентам.

Answer (score 1):

Один ― многозначное слово.

ОДИН, 4. **Определённый** (из числа однородных лиц, предметов, явлений). Одна из моих книг потеряна. 5. **Первый или каждый** (из числа однородных лиц, предметов, явлений). Один день сменился другим.

**Получается два значения**: Один из замов ― определенный (Иван Иванович), один из замов - любой, какой-нибудь.

**Поэтому так и будут говорить** (выбор самого простого  варианта): Устроили мероприятие, но не пригласили ни самого начальника, ни одного из замов. "Один" здесь ― любой, какой-либо.

Comment: Плохо, во-первых, из-за неоднозначности, во-вторых, даже во втором случае (один = любой) смысл немного не тот: рассматривается возможность пригласить любого, но только одного зама. Могли, дескать пригласить начальника и/или одного из замов, но не сделали ни того, ни другого. Сравните: Могли пригласить начальника и/или его замов, но не пригласили начальника и не пригласили ни одного из замов.

Comment: Это ваш же вариант №1: Не пригласили ни самого начальника, ни кого-нибудь из замов.

Comment: "Кого-нибудь из замов" подразумевает одного или несколько человек. Не так ли?

Comment: Информация ясная: не было замов (первого, второго, третьего), никого из них не было. Что тут еще думать и подразумевать?

Comment: Есть разница в нюансах. Когда говорят, что чего-то не сделали, подразумевают не результат (не было замов), а упущенную возможность. И тут маленькое отличие: (1) пригласить одного зама;  (2) пригласить кого-нибудь из замов (то есть одного или несколько замов).

Comment: Знаете,  нюансы, может, и существуют, но кому они нужны. Журналист должен передать определенную информацию, и думаю, что точный подсчет замов в его задачу не входил.  А вот ситуация смутная, я  не понимаю, какой там подтекст.  Каков статус мероприятия,  каков уровень начальника? Когда приглашают начальника, а когда и зам сойдет? Вот если бы он сам не счел нужным приехать и даже зама не послал. Короче говоря, текст  с неясным смыслом, и количество замов здесь последнее дело. Хорошо разбираться с грамматикой там, где понятна семантика, в противном случае это напрасная трата времени.

Comment: Други мои! Я не знаю, что они там имели в виду. Но врял ди они противопоставляли возможность пригласить одного зама приглашению одного начальника. Скорее всего противопоставлялось неприглашение (никого не пригласили) приглашению кого-то мз них всех (одного или более). М_Г в своих вариантах правильно передал смысл, но сместил акценты, почему мне эти варианты и не нравятся. В математике  "не (пригласил) ни кого-нибудь из" означает "не пригласил никого". А вот в языке - сильно сомневаюсь, что так однозначно. Тут противопоставление приглашению начальника приглашению замов прёт, куда ни прячься...

Answer (score 1):

Оптимальный вариант:

***Устроили мероприятие, но не пригласили ни самого начальника, ни кого из замов.***

Comment: Именно так, с раздельным написание "ни кого"? Но вообще - да интересно. Немножко отдаёт утрированной разговорностью.  Но в целом - плюс.

Comment: _Morkovkin: Именно так, с раздельным написание "ни кого"?_  === Да, с раздельным. См. примеры: _После этого мне ни разу не случалось встречать ни отца, **ни кого из** своих прежних знакомых_ (Джеймс Гринвуд "Маленький оборвыш"); _Я ни за что ни вас, **ни кого из** товарищей не подведу!_  (Аркадий Гайдар "Школа").

Answer (score 0):

О! Я понял.

***Не пригласили и ни начальника, и ни одного зама.*** - Вот это точный авторский смысл и акценты, если я правильно понимаю. Только очень витиевато и не совсем по-русски. Уберите как-то лексическими средствами повторяющееся и - и вопрос решен.

Comment: А вот такой вариант: Не пригласили начальника и (даже) ни одного из замов.

Answer (score 0):

Мне показался подходящим следующий вариант: **Устроили мероприятие, но не пригласили ни самого начальника, ни кого-либо из замов**.